# Can't Change Vote!

Tags: feature-request, voting

I downvoted an answer because I thought it didn't satisfy the original request, but the user who provided the answer replied to my comment that the solution was generalized a bit, and that a different case was provided from what OP used as an example.

It seems silly that I can't update my vote based on that information unless the post is edited.

Comment: *"Unless the post is edited."* So you are aware of the work-around.  This kind of feature request is not specific to Mathematica.StackExchange and there is nothing that community moderators (like me) can do about it.  If you feel strongly about it go to [Meta.SE] but I am sure this has been discussed before so search before posting.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard , thanks for letting me know. I checked and it looks like others have had the same problem if anyone wants to show support with thoroughly considered, unalterable upvotes, [meta.stackexchange #191457](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191457/unable-to-change-vote-or-unvote-answers) :)

Comment: That post seems to be about a side issue.  I think [(6250)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6250/121) is much closer, however you will find that it has been marked "status-bydesign."

Comment: I pasted the wrong link. That is the link I meant. I even commented in that thread : /

Answer (score 5):

Since you have more than 2000 reputation points, you can edit any question or answer. That taken with Mr.Wizard's hint should tell you how you reverse your down-vote. Consider making an edit with no visual effect or two edits, the 2nd undoing the 1st.